# can't see output of dbveaver with raise commands

Tags: dbeaver

My code:

```
do $$
declare
        nombre TEXT;
        ultima_dependencia TEXT;
        primera_cadena TEXT;
        segunda_cadena TEXT;
        TOTAL CURSOR for select  ANTERIOR as nombre, split_part(dependencia, '#', 2) AS ULTIMA_DEPENDENCIA from PROC_ANT;
    begin   
    RAISE notice 'I got here';
    RAISE notice 'PEROO QUEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE';
    OPEN TOTAL;
            LOOP
                  fetch TOTAL into nombre, ultima_dependencia;              
                  RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', nombre;
             EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
            end loop;
    close TOTAL;
    end;
$$;
```

I can't see anything in output tab of dbeaver:

[image]

I need to see output in dbbeaver